# How to create a popup that lets the user type in their name with javascript

Tags: javascript, android

I am starting to create a small android game using Phonegap, but I am having a bit of trouble on this one part.

What is the code that I should use, so that a popup appears asking the user to type in their username, and when they click okay, everything else changes to that username, so it would say something like Welcome *Name* etc.

*Edit* Is there any way to do this without using a prompt?

Comment: the code you need is (z-index)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for just a basic system prompt, you can use the native prompt function and save the entered value into a variable and tie that to your HTML

```
var name = prompt('Enter your name');
```

Assuming you don't want to use prompt, you could create your own div that shows/hides based on some criteria with a form/input in it and when the form is submitted, save the input value and do it that way. This sort of thing is VERY easy with jQuery and relatively easy with vanilla JavaScript.

```
<div class="prompt">
    <form name="myPrompt">
        <label for="name">User name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required>
        <input type="submit" id="submitPrompt" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

And then in your JavaScript file.

```
document.getElementById('submitPrompt').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    document.querySelector('prompt').style.display = 'none';
    var username = document.getElementsByName('name')[0];
    /* do something cool with username */
});
```

This is not really great code, but should get you started at least.

Comment: Thanks for your help.